# Running a testsuite in Robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a robot framework testcase file with the name 'mytestsuite.txt'. It has few test cases..I can run this suite using,

`pybot mytestsuite.txt`

But when I tried to execute it using --suite option,

`pybot --suite mytestsuite.txt`

getting the error ,

`[ ERROR ] Expected at least 1 argument, got 0.`

Is anything wrong in this ,or anyone can suggest how to execute the testsuite file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pybot --suite mytestsuite /path/to/mytestuite-dir` So drop the `.txt` and put path to the directory where the suite is at the end of the command.

Comment: @Harri : can you please help in this problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350356/check-table-content-using-robotframework-selenium2-python